# Is it possible to host (or mimicking hosting) of views withing live wallpaper?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-canvas, android-bitmap, live-wallpaper

### background

I've made a simple app called "[**LWP+**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.lwp_plus)", which shows a cropped image . When the user chooses a photo, I save it into a file, and then do the cropping when needed. I do this by using 2 libraries. One for allowing the user to choose the cropping rectangle, and one for the actual cropping.

### The problem

This is just for a normal cropping, but a nicer feature I'd like to add is a way to scroll through the content of the entire given image, at least horizontally.

On a normal Activity, I'd probably use a `ViewPager` that has an ImageView for each page.

But here a live wallpaper doesn't really have a layout.

### What I've found

There isn't much of information about live wallpapers in general, but when I've searched for scrolling of an image in it, I've found just how to move the canvas.

This can actually be a good idea, of somehow having bitmaps (or partial decoding of the image) around the current position, and translating the canvas as needed. I could also use a `GestureDetector` class to identify flinging, but this is only a tiny fraction of what's needed to do a nice scrolling of a zoomed image.

It is also very complex, as it requires good memory considerations in mind.

If I could use a normal view, I could have used a `ViewPager`, or even a third library that shows an image and allows to scroll in it freely , like in the gallery app (such as [**this one**](https://github.com/Piasy/BigImageViewer)).

### The question

1. Given a View of any kind, such as `ViewPager` or another, is it possible to host it somehow inside the LiveWallpaper, to let it show content, and to handle touch events ?
2. Alternatively, is there an efficient way to view content as I've written, yet in a live wallpaper? Meaning viewing a portion of a large image, while allowing to scroll though it (like a `ViewPager`, but maybe even freely like on a photo viewer library, in all directions) ?